# Encrypting digits of a numeric input

Tags: python, encryption

Imagine that I have a 4-digit numeric input, 9092, for example. If I want to add +1 to each digit of that number, so that 9 becomes 0, 0 becomes 1, and 2 becomes 3, what should I do?

Comment: Use the modulus operator (%).

Comment: Please post in future code of your attempts to solve the problem. It's not a place to find somebody to solve it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some Code.

```
x=input("Please Enter Any number: ") #=== Input
y=[char for char in x] #== List of characters
print(y)
for j,i in enumerate(y):
    if int(i)==9: #== if i=9
        y[j]='0' #=== Replace that index with 0
    else:
        print(i)
        y[j]=str(int(i)+1) #== Replace that index with num+1
print(''.join(y)) #=== Print joined slist
```

```
input: 9092
output: 0103
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the best solution, but it works.

```
num = 9092
 
print("".join([str((int(n)+1)%10) for n in str(num)]))
```

Output:

```
0103
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I put 9092, I returned 103, not 0103. In this specific coding case, the 0 on the left makes a difference.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it so it returned a string instead to deal with leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

that should work:

```
tmp = [int(i) for i in str(9092)]
output = ""
for i in range(len(tmp)):
    if tmp[i] == 9:
        tmp[i] = 0
    else:
        tmp[i] = tmp[i] + 1
    output = output + str(tmp[i])
print(int(output))
```